# How to get a list of which packages were installed with apt-get by a user and not by dependencies?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Say I'm running a Debian based distro and I want to know what packages I ran `apt-get install <package-name>` to install, but I didn't want to include any packages that were auto-installed as dependencies when I installed another package using `apt-get install <package-name>`...would there be a way to find this out?

My guess is that there isn't a way because `apt` and `dpkg` probably don't differentiate between the two, but I'd prefer to be proved wrong if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages installed as dependencies are marked as automatically installed. You can see and manipulate these markers with [`apt-mark`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt-mark.8).

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

will list packages which aren’t marked as automatically installed, *i.e.* packages installed explicitly.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `aptitude` et al. show these marks next to the package names.

Answer (score 1):

These commands may help you make easier your work, I would try the following command:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep 'apt-get install '
```

Following two commands:

```
apt-mark showmanual

dpkg --get-selections
```

are not 100% way of achieving that task and finding out which were installed by user and which as dependencies or auto installed, but the first command might be a little bit helpful.

**An important note**, if you are running a logrotate utility, You will have to use the following command

```
zgrep 'apt-get install' /var/log/apt/history* --color
```

Comment: Rarely any need for `cat` when there's just a single file. `grep 'apt-get install' /var/log/apt/history.log`